# BIND9 does not listen on external ip

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to configure the bind to broadcast my domain around the external network, but my server is not listening on the external ip.

Everything works fine locally.

my web interface:

```
 enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
       inet INTERNAL_IP  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.55.255
       inet6 INTERNAL_IP_V6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>


 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
       inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
       inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
       loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
```

even with iptables turned off:

```
sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

named.conf.options:

```
    options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    statistics-file "/run/named/named.stats";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

     forwarders {
            x.x.x.x;     # gateway or router
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
            external ip;
     };

    dnssec-validation auto;

    listen-on-v6 port 53 {any;};

    listen-on port 53 {any;};

    auth-nxdomain yes;            # conform to RFC1035
    allow-query { any; };         # allow anyone to issue queries
    allow-recursion { any; };
    allow-query-cache { any; };
    recursion no;                 # disallow recursive queries
    version "[SECURED]";
};
```

netstat:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :53
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 INTERNAL_IP:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 INTERNAL_IP:53          0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

ufw:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
DNS                        ALLOW       Anywhere
DNS (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

nmap shows:

```
53/tcp filtered domain
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help, Slawek.

Comment: Have you enabled port forwarding on your router for port 53 (udp and tcp)?

Comment: This seems to be full of misconceptions. DNS doesn't broadcast anything. None of the given details are relevant regarding whether BIND listens on external IP address, whatever it means. Are you behind a NAT? In that case you'd need a port forwarding. But then, if you are behind a NAT, it's probably not the best idea to host an authoritative DNS server there. Also, every public domain name requires at least two name servers. https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements

Comment: yes, my server is behind nat, i have redirected ports, i know about two name servers. So, since my server is too nat, I can't broadcast the name on the external network? I only do it "for fun" to learn something. Probably the easiest way would be to redirect A NS records to an external server and after the problem, but that's a simple solution. sorry for my English

Comment: Can you clarify whether bind works in the "internal" network? That host looks to be only connected to the "internal" network, so if it works there but not from the internet(?) the problem statement seems to be barking up the wrong tree, ie in that case it would appear to be purely a port forwarding issue unrelated to bind itself.

Comment: Yes, on the internal network, everything works fine, it works on every domain I configure. I cannot connect to the Internet via the domain, the delegation was carried out only 12 hours ago, and I haven't done the full configuration the bind yet, because it seems to me that it does not listen on port 53. Other ports work properly, for example, if I enter the external IP my server in to browser (different internet connection) the website is displayed correctly.

Comment: as this is no business case please move your question to superuser. Because serverfault.com is for business purposes only

Comment: djdomi- how do this?

Comment: @EsaJokinen "Also, every public domain name requires at least two name servers. iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements" Not 100% true. The IANA requirements apply to TLDs, not "every public domain name". Each registry is free to set their own rules. And you can have registered domain names without any nameservers at all. OF course they won't resolve, but they still are valid "public domain name".

Comment: It is also possible that your ISP blocks self hosted DNS servers because badly configured DNS are easy to use to drive DDoS attacks

Comment: I checked and the server works, I set a constant ip dns to my server on the computer in the internal network, I turned off redirects in it and the pages start (longer the first time, but then normal). I am now waiting for a contact from a friend of a friend, whether and for what other dns he conducted the delegation. @Esa Jokinen was probably right, which made me think the server would not work, it didn't matter, I should check first :)

Comment: No offense, but if you want to learn, I suggest you start with reading the DNS & BIND book from O'Reilly instead of creating public facing DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

I Test your configurations with bind9 on ubuntu 22. It is working. I think your port forwarding is not working well. You should port forward for both tcp and udp protocols

Answer (score -1):

To close, it pauses the fun temporarily, no time. Thank you for your interest, I know what else I need to check. Greetings.